# нужно подправить, что бы считало по другим формулам

Tags: python, django, калькулятор

вот как выглядит таблица:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вот как выглядит мой корявый models py:

```
from django.db import models


class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Название')
    composition = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Состав')
    price = models.FloatField(verbose_name='Цена за 100 грамм')
    grams_per_person = models.FloatField(verbose_name='Грамм на человека')
    weight = models.FloatField(verbose_name='Заказ (грамм)')
    published = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, db_index=True, verbose_name='Время')
    total_price = models.FloatField(default=0, verbose_name='Стоимость заказа')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name[:25]

    def calculate_price(self):
        total = (self.price * self.weight) / 100
        return total

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.total_price = round(float(self.calculate_price()), 2)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Позиции'
        verbose_name = 'Позиция'
        ordering = ['published']
```

нужно применить вот такие формулы: К колонке "Заказ грамм" применяем формулу: Заказ грамм/1чел Х на кол-во гостей,), К колонке "Стоимость заказа" применяем формулу: "Цена" Х "Заказ грамм" / 100.

как это сделать/что добавить?

Comment: Не понятно. В какой момент должен происходить расчёт? Если сразу при изменении значения в поле, без отправки формы методом POST,  то это проще сделать с помощью JavaScript.

Comment: Если данные о заказе хранятся в БД, то это должна быть отдельная модель, которая имеет атрибут Foreighkey, ссылающийся на Product. А Product не должен описывать общие характеристики заказа, а лишь описание продукта и его цену за 100 грамм. Заказ и продукт это разные сущности, которые лучше не смешивать в одну модель.